# Embed Rich Formatted Text File into HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to load the contents of a TXT file into an HTML page. The catch is, the TXT file contains HTML tag references therein. In this case, the plain text contents of the TXT file contains numerous B tags to bold certain portions of text, while all other portions of text are plain.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_b.asp

Here is my relevant code so far:

```
<div id="help-screen" class="screen">
    <object id="help-text" type="text/plain" data="gui/help.txt"></object>
</div>

var helpText = document.getElementById("help-text");
helpText.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("help-screen").innerHTML = helpText.contentDocument.body.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
};
```

What this code does so far is successfully loads the contents of the TXT file into the HTML page. The HTML document as a whole declares a default text font, color, and size which the loaded in TXT contents are appropriately styled to.

Problem is, all the line breaks in the TXT document are skipped and the B tags are skipped too.

I tried renaming my help.txt file to help.html and removing the type attribute. However, the result is that "undefined" appears on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I simply removed the reference to 'childNodes[0]' and it works.